# Integrating Oracle ADF JSF Pages to MS SharePoint

Tags: shared-service-provider, oracle

In my organization we use MS SharePoint to build internal communication sites, connecting with all employees, forums, repositories etc. There is a small team here coming up with an idea of creating an internal classifieds page using Oracle ADF. I would like to understand if this JSF pages can be integrated with MS SharePoint?

Any thoughts... please advice.

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 2):

This sounds immensely challenging and yet a wholly unique concept.

Without iframes I don't it see it as being possible, however it may be more possible to integrate Sharepoint functionality into a seperate JSF web application.

You can look into [Sharepoint Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479390%28v=office.12%29.aspx) which allow for remote Sharepoint functionality in non-Sharepoint embedded pages.  I used these web services to write an external ASP.NET application that integrated with Sharepoint so similar concepts can be used with JSF on the middle tier through web service interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can if be done through Page Viewer Web Part? Is this making us of iframes?

Comment: @Arun, I believe it does use iframes actually.  You can try making a quick prototype using a page viewer web part to show Google just to verify.

Comment: Sure.. will try doing that. My another concern is on deploying the Oracle ADF JSF pages to the server.

Comment: @Arun, `deploying the Oracle ADF JSF pages to the server` and after you figure this out you can help me figure out how to use my car as a dishwasher :)  JSF technology is an abstraction of JEE Servlets so unless somebody writes a JSF implementation per the JSF 2 spec in ASP.NET this will not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably show it on SharePoint by using:

[Page Viewer Web Part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/page-viewer-web-part-HA010024045.aspx)

But in general it is like mixing [apples and oranges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apples_and_oranges).

Comment: Hmm... true. Thanks for your suggestion on Page Viewer Web Part.